# jquery .unload() only triggering for first page accessed in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have parent.html with iframe. Source of iframe is child1.html which links to child2.html which links back to child1.html

**parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is the parent</p>
        <iframe id="frame1" src="child1.html"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var frame1ChildWindow = document.getElementById("frame1").contentWindow;
            $( frame1ChildWindow ).unload(function() {
                console.log('unload triggered');
            });
            $('#frame1').load( function() {         
                console.log('load triggered');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**child1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is child page 1</p>
        <p><a href="child2.html">Go to child page 2</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**child2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is child page 2</p>
        <p><a href="child1.html">Go to child page 1</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the .unload() and the .load() to be triggered every time you navigate between child1.html and child2.html but currently only the .load() is triggered every time. The .unload() is only triggered on the child1.html page and is not triggered again for all subsequent navigations.

Could someone please

1. explain why .unload() is only triggered on the child1.html page
2. show how to get .unload() triggered every time you navigate between
   child1.html and child2.html

Comment: Does this happen if you enclose the javascript into a jquery `document.ready` statement? Also if you change the `$( frame1ChildWindow ).unload(function() {` to `$( frame1ChildWindow ).on( "unload", function() { `?

Comment: @rodrigogq thanks for suggestions, tried both and got exactly the same result

Comment: @rodrigogq apologies, my above testing was flawed, turns out that .unload() was triggering on child1.html only and once I noticed this I was able to solve. I will update question and post answer. Cheers.

Comment: Have you trying to attach the `$('#frame1').unload( function() {` directly? Otherwise, it seems that you are hanging an `unload` function handler on that window just when the main page loads. When you follow the link, it seems that since this windows is destroyed to the next page's window. So either you attach to the iframe or try setting it along other events.

Comment: @rodrigogq yes, one of the first things I tried was attaching the .unload() to the iframe in parent but it does not trigger, although the .load() is attached in this way and does trigger. Would you know why this is? Please see my answer below, this is working for me, do you see any potential issue with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the .unload() was only triggering on the child1.html page because when you navigate to child2.html then the variable frame1ChildWindow no longer exists as it is the contentWindow of child1.html.

To get the .unload() to trigger for every page I put the binding within the .load() function so that it binds to each child contentWindow that loads within the iframe.

```
$('#frame1').load( function() {         
    console.log('load triggered');
    var frame1ChildWindow = document.getElementById("frame1").contentWindow;
    $( frame1ChildWindow ).unload(function() {
        console.log('unload triggered');
    });
});
```

This should allow me to show a loading div/gif for any page navigated to from within the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the `.unload()` documentation, it states that the unload event is fired to let javascripts execute cleanup codes, but it cannot prevent (or cancel) the browser from the default action the user is taking, which can be navigating to another link (in your case, child2.html).

So I had to update the unload trigger every time your new window is created, that is, when your window is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is the parent</p>
        <iframe id="frame1" src="child1.html"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

              // function for setting an unload callback function
              function setChildUnload(callback)
              {
                var documentChild = $('#frame1').prop("contentWindow").document;
                var childWindow = $('#frame1').prop("contentWindow");

                // we need to wait for child's ready function
                $(documentChild).ready(function() {
                  $(childWindow).unload(callback);
                });
              }

              // unload callback
              function myUnload()
              {
                  console.log('unload triggered');
              }

              $('#frame1').load( function() {         
                  console.log('load triggered');

                 // set the callback when child page is loaded
                setChildUnload(myUnload);
              });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, every time you navigate away from a page, the `window` object is destroyed along with your `unload` handler. I am setting it again when the new page and its windows is loaded.

The load function doesn't seem to work in that way, since you can attach to the iframe object, which is not destroyed along page navigation.